# Can not get data from AJAX request to the Coinhive API

Tags: javascript, php, json, api

I recently tried to get the data from a Json API and post that back to a table in html.
I tried to do this from: `https://api.coinhive.com/user/balance?name=username&secret=mysecret` 
It does show me: `{"success":true,"name":"*user*","total":49152,"withdrawn":0,"balance":* a value *}`

But I want to let my users push a button which will load the balance value to a table in their own user portal.

I got the user portal setup with all the [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)values, But i can't manage to get the [json](/questions/tagged/json)part to work.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in common,
Dennis.

edit:

I tried the following:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaScript - read JSON from URL</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mypanel"></div>

    <script>
    $.getJSON('https://api.coinhive.com/user/balance?name=username&secret=mysecret', function(data) {

        var text = `Balance: ${data.balance}<br>`


        $(".mypanel").html(text);
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And I also tried:

```
function setup() {
    loadJSON("https://api.coinhive.com/user/balance?name=username&secret=mysecret", gotData);
}

function gotData(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

And that isn't working.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say "table" are you referring to the HTML `<table>` tag or are you talking about the SQL table?

Comment: What did you do to receive and process JSON data? Please show your code.

Comment: @dustin, i am referring to the html table.

Comment: I deleted the code after several hours of rewriting. I also search across stackoverflow to find someone with the same problem. When trying other example json files it did just work, I just don't know why the app json didn't

Comment: So you've got this JSON from the API into your page, and you want to push it to a database on your server, right? What you need is an ajax request which will send that JSON to your server. Have you tried to do that?

Comment: That sounds really good, I don't know how to pull that off. I want to get back the balance value, it would be best if it will get stored inside mysql since I can get the user values from the logged in user.

Comment: I edited my post with the code I tried.

Comment: @Unf0rg0tt3n Add `fail` handler ([jQuery.getJSON() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)). Are there any errors in the console of your web browser? Please show data from the `data` variable.

Comment: Hi  @camelsWriteInCamelCase No errors, even no output in de console. I will ad the fail handler when I get home from work and hope there will be output.

Comment: I still fail to understand the question. Are you trying to display the data on an HTML table or push it to a SQL table. Your response to my comment implies you want to display in in an HTML table. And then you edited your question to say something about an SQL database... what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get the result in a html table.
After that I need to get it in mysql, but my main problem is actually showing it in a HTML Table

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase I got the following error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out!

The JSON request:

```
<?php
$url = 'the api url';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
));

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($data, true);

?>
```

The postback to the end user:

```
<span id="test" style="color:white"><?php
if (isset($data))
{
   echo $result['balance'];
}
else
{
   echo 'damn';
}
?></span>
```

I decided to go with php and kind of ditch the html getjson part.

Answer (score 0):

Client side requests to the Coinhive HTTP API are restricted by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) rules:

[From API documentation](https://coinhive.com/documentation/http-api):

> You should never call the Coinhive HTTP API from the client side.

Comment: You indeed shouldn't from the client side.
My last post was the solution, which is used with php.

Thanks though, for pointing me to the right directions in your posts.
I used php cURL which was easier to combine with my users's interaction