# Get coinhive api http site/stats from my website

Tags: php, json, api, http

Just a beginner here. I'm trying to get the site/stats from the coinhive api for my website.

From this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/47401074/9900539 I have found codes snippets that seem to be what I am looking for.

But where do I put what?

The JSON request:

```
<?php
$url = 'the api url';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
));

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($data, true);

?>
```

The postback to the end user:

```
<span id="test" style="color:white"><?php
if (isset($data))
{
   echo $result['balance'];
}
else
{
   echo 'not found';
}
?></span>
```

Comment: Be carefully, users should know that they are executing code related to coinhive. If not that could be a case for the court.

Comment: Whats? Please elaborate.

Comment: Coinhive scripts are used in many kinds to mine without the users agreement and are treated as virus by probably most or even all anti-virus scanners. Using other people CPU- / GPU- time to mine coins for the own usage without agreement can be treated as felony and it was already.

Answer (score 0):

Coinhive actually provides a [PHP wrapper](https://gist.github.com/coinhive-com/dc37d300b2f4f909006a07139c9d2c71) for its HTTP API. According to [its documentation](https://coinhive.com/documentation/http-api), it can perform basic stat requests more conveniently than your code snippets.